# How to use AddIdentity<User, Role> in dotnet core 7?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net core 7 and AspNetCore.Identity 7. I wanna register identity to dependency injection system in IoC layer:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Eshop.Entities;

namespace Eshop.IoCConfig;

public static class AddCustomServicesExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomService(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // some code

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

But there's error:

> IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddIdentity

Comment: Are you just missing an import? Try `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem and use `AddIdentityCore<TUser>` instead of `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>`:

```
 services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
        .AddRoles<Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EshopDbContext>();
```